# accessing java object from hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am accessing a java object which is saved in `hazelcast map` from some other upstream system. I have the same java object structure but when I read the object and try to typecast it to my java object it throws `ClassCast` exception because my java object lies in some different package. How should we serialize the object while saving it in hazelcast so that it won't matter where my mapping java object reside(package)

---

**Object in HZ**

```
package com.varun.customer.bo;
  public class Customer{
     private long customerId;
 }
```

---

**My Object**

```
package com.varun.customer;
  public class Customer{
     private long customerId;
 }
```

Check the difference in package of both objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an application where you can have common classes and try using from that package at both the places. It will easy to maintain as you will need to change at 1 place.

Comment: that solution works if you are building something new... you get that control. But when you are working with existing ages old code sort of enterprise integration project you loose that liberty. Thats why i asked it in forum.Thanks for your reply though !

Answer (score 0):

Hazelcast has [several ways to serialize objects](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.6/manual/html-single/index.html#serialization-interface-types).

I suppose, you can try [Custom serialization](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.8.6/manual/html-single/index.html#custom-serialization) and implement your serialization/deserialization logic in `write`/`read` methods of `StreamSerializer` or  `ByteArraySerializer` for each of your packages.